# Retina devices won't read retina css

Tags: css, stylesheet, retina-display

I'm working on a new website which has to support `Retina displays`. After some html/css `@media` queries, very much research and unbelievable high number of tests, it still didn't work.

So to solve my problem I created this basic "Do I have a Retina display?"-page. (code below):

```
<title>Retina Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: green; }
    @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
        background-color:blue;
    }
</style>
```

I used `background-color` just for the basic testing. Might good to know, I've got some retina devices to test on: a retina macbook pro and a retina iPhone 4.

Thanks in forward.
Bob

Comment: did you try using `media screen ... `

Comment: Did try `<link rel="stylesheet" media="...." href="http://foo.bar.com/stylesheet.css" />`?

Comment: does your body have any content? if not - it might just have a height of 0 and that's why you can't see the BG color

Comment: Yes, I used media screens...
No, the body has no content, but I adjusted it a little, since there could be this problam "Zoltan Toth" is explaining.

Adjusted version:

<title>Retina Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: green; height:30px width:30px;}
  @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    background-color:blue; height:30px; width:30px;
    }
   }
</style>

Comment: You aren't selecting anything inside of your media query. Might that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
body {background-color: green;}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) { // targets iphone retina?
    body{background-color:blue;}
}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {   // targets macbook retina?
    body{background-color:blue;}
}
```

If you want to change the font color, the correct usage is:

```
body {color: green;}
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    body{color:blue;}
}
```

Note that I have no way to test if `@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5)` actually targets retina displays.

Comment: Shmiddty: I can't see a difference between your code and mine. Anyway I just copied your code and used it. Unfortunately it still doesn't work + why is your "and" blue and mine black? So I expanded my code a little to: http://pastebin.com/k6AnNrs7 since you guys think the body part is the problem. But guess what, I'm still seeing green on my retina screen...

Comment: Inside your media query you aren't selecting anything. Essentially you're saying `Set the background-color of NOTHING to blue.`

Comment: I'm not talking about the background-color, I'm talking about the font colors of this website (difference between yours and mine). I edited my code a little, added your suggestion and changed the colors to simpler color, red for non-retina green for retina...


`<html>
<head>
<title>Retina Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: red;
}

@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
body {
background-color:green;
}
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: If you're trying to change background color, use the `color` property.

Comment: update: with current changes the iPhone displays a green screen (works), but the Retina Macbook won't...

Comment: I believe the setting for MacBook is 2 for pixel-ratio.

Comment: Sorry people, this is too stupid for words. My screen settings where false (default). Make sure your resolution is on "best for retina"  not "scaled"

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
background-color:blue;
```

to:

```
body {background-color:blue}
```

That should do it.